# Ionic capacitor app shows only white blank screen in ios

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an app developed in Ionic it is working fine in Web and Android it is even in Google Play Store right now but when I try to run it on simulator or device it just show a blank white screen not even splashscreen.

[image]

Comment: Can you connect the device to `xcode` and show the logs?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the information given it could be anything.

Neverless i had a similar issue maybe this helps somebody:

With **no errors in log in xcode**, just an empty screen on IOS physical and emulator device.
**For Android, Browser (Safari, etc), ionic live reload** on physical device **it worked.**

My issue is related to **Angular fire AuthGuard** which seems not to be working as expected for IOS 16.1.
After **deleting the AuthGuard** in *App Routing Module*, my screens where getting loaded - currently trying to figure out what was wrong.

This is more a hint for people, maybe to check if they have same issue

**EDIT**

My Issue was related to: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3087

Using dependencies provided by DeezCashews in Issue saved my day

```
"@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
"firebase": "^9.6.4",
"rxfire": "^6.0.3"
```

Seems there is an issue with Angular Fire and ionic capacitor.

Answer (score -1):

It solved mine:
In  capacitor.config.json file, we have an object, we need to change “webDir” default value is “src”

```
{
    …
    “webDir”: “src”
    …
}

//“webDir” value will be “www”.
```

Comment: i already added this

{
    …
    “webDir”: “www”
    …
}

Comment: did you check if this is not the launcher